# Change element after downloading a file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button on my page that sets the current page location to an page that generates a PDF on my server. Because it takes a few seconds to generate and send the file, I want to inform the user that their click was received and is processing, so I added a spinner to the download process.

```
$("#download-pdf-button").click(function() {                        
    // some code to display a spinner

    window.location.href = "/path/to/downloadGeneratingPage";

    // some code to hide the spinner
});
```

The download works fine, but the way this code executes, the spinner is hidden immediately. I'd like to find a way make it so the spinner shows, and once the server has sent back it's request, the spinner is hidden again.

I've tried a few other options, like using `$.get()` and sending the data to a hidden iframe, but that doesn't allow me to suggest a file name like I can with my server's HTTP response (but it does allow me to hide the spinner at the point I want it to be hidden). The name isn't a huge issue (nice to have, however) but I need to at least add the extension so users can open it without renaming it.

Basically what I want is:

- Display spinner when the request is sent
- Have file download upon browser receiving it (I can change the server side code, e.g. send different HTTP headers, if needed)
- Hide spinner when file is received
- Allow me to add file extension

Answer (score 1):

Setting a value in `window.location.href` will unload your current page and load the page you define. The code after that statement will not be executed.

What you probably want is [an ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
//Code to show the spinner
$.ajax( "/path/to/downloadGeneratingPage" ).done( function( data ) {
  //Code to hide the spinner and do something with the data the server sent back
} );
```

Comment: +1, and as a wild guess I would add that maybe the response could bring a `Content-disposition: attachment` to force the browser to show the "save as" dialog. Not sure if it would work at all, though.

Comment: It only unloads the current page if the browser displays it. As I said, it works fine as-is, and code after that line does get executed (I added an alert afterwards because I suspected the same, but it showed up...just before the PDF finished downloading).

I also mentioned I tried `$.get()` which is a wrapper for an `$.ajax()` call. 

@orique It already does that. The problem is, those headers are useless if I try to use an ajax call to load it somewhere, because any manipulation done with the data is no longer an HTTP request.